# Can I remove the last entry in a firebase query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I am trying to accomplish is to query 11 entries and then removed the first one, for example:

```
ref.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(11).once('value')
```

this will give me the highest 11 entries by score.

Then I wish I can:

```
ref.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(11).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.removeFirstChild();
})
```

Comment: do you want to remove the item from firebase or only in the local?

Comment: @MuruGan from firebase, I kinda figure it out. I need to sort the snapshot and then use the key to delete the entry.

Comment: that is what I am asking, do you want to use the key to delete the entry in the firebase itself or in the local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
ref.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(11).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
  var isFirst = true;
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    if (isFirst) {
      child.remove();
      isFirst = false;
    }
})
```

Or:

```
ref.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(11).once('child_added').then((snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.remove();
})
```

Comment: I think forEach is an async function. The second method just remove all 11 entries. :)

Comment: `DataSnapshot.forEach` is a synchronous method. The second snippet listens to `child_added` **once**, which means it only gets triggered for the first child that matches the conditions.

Comment: I see. Smart move. Thanks!